# How old is מדרש ר׳ עקיבא בן יוסף אל אותיות קטנות?

Tags: history, midrash

I stumbled on [these](https://www.sefaria.org/Otzar_Midrashim%2C_Midrashim_of_Rabbi_Akiba%2C_The_Small_Letters_and_their_Purposes?lang=bi) midrashim, I'm curious as to how old they are...

Comment: The first time they showed up in publication was in Amsterdam in 1708.

Comment: According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alphabet_of_Rabbi_Akiva), one version of the midrashim was around at least by the 10th century.